# Creating tar using maven-antrun-plugin in java 11

Tags: java, tar

In pom.xml, I am creating tar using maven-antrun-plugin.The tar file is creating successfully

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
   <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>prepare tar for jdk</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
            <target>
                <unzip
                    src="/tmp/openjdk-11.0.6.zip"
                    dest="${project.build.directory}/tmp" />
                <tar
                    destfile="/openjdk-11.0.6.tar"
                    basedir="${project.build.directory}/tmp"
                    excludes="openjdk-11.0.6.zip" />
            </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

But while untaring I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.Error: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: File format not recognised
```

Could some help me to resolve this?

Comment: How are you untaring? Also update your question with complete error log.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: File format not recognised
        at java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.load(ZoneInfoFile.java:295)
        at java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:258)   and Untar command is tar -xf "filename"

Comment: Better to update your question the complete log rather than in comments and also update question with how are you untaring the file.

Comment: I am unable to post full stack here. In shell script we are using "tar -xf filename'

Comment: Are you running `tar` command from command line?

Comment: Yes in linux machine I am running

Comment: How can you get a java error `java.io.StreamCorruptedException` while using tar command from command line?